# How do you call a service method from a class?

Tags: android, multithreading, service, android-service

I have a service, and within this service I have created a class Client that implements Runnable. I call this client in the onCreate of my service using

```
clientThread = new Thread(new Client());
clientThread.start();
```

In the client class, I have a long running operation, and have some data that I would like to print to my Activity. In my service, I have a method (sendToUI) that sends data to the Activity, and the Activity uses a handler to receive the data.

Now my question is, how can my Client class use the method(sendToUI), which is in my service, to feed it's data into my Activity?

Thanks in advance for any help.

**Update:** I did some reading, and found a simple way (in my view) that solved my problem. Here is the process I used.

I added a global variable to my Client class, which I updated constantly in the run() method. I then added a method (getValue) to my Client class, which returned the global variable.

I changed my code to

```
Client clientthread = new Client();
new Thread(clientthread).start();
```

in order to start the thread. I then used

```
int value = clientthread.getValue();
```

in order to retrieve the current value of the global variable in my Client class. I then called my sendToUi method with the value as its parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind to that service from your activity with a binder that returns the instance of the service. then you can simply invoke whatever method you want with that service instance.

The only problem with this approach is that the binding is done asynchronously, and for a lot of use cases thats going to be a pain! unfourtunately i am not aware of any better approach.

```
public class LocalService extends Service {
// Binder given to clients
private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
// Random number generator
private final Random mGenerator = new Random();

/**
 * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
 * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
 */
public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
    LocalService getService() {
        // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
        return LocalService.this;
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return mBinder;
}

/** method for clients */
public int getRandomNumber() {
  return mGenerator.nextInt(100);
}
```

}

```
public class BindingActivity extends Activity {
LocalService mService;
boolean mBound = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // Unbind from the service
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
}

/** Called when a button is clicked (the button in the layout file attaches to
  * this method with the android:onClick attribute) */
public void onButtonClick(View v) {
    if (mBound) {
        // Call a method from the LocalService.
        // However, if this call were something that might hang, then this request should
        // occur in a separate thread to avoid slowing down the activity performance.
        int num = mService.getRandomNumber();
        Toast.makeText(this, "number: " + num, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

}

see [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the *UI Thread*, using the method *runOnUiThread* like following:

```
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // ... Excecute the code for the Activity here
        }
    });
```

Put this code into your class.

I hope it's useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should notify your Activity class that some data has to be updated on the UI. You shouldn't update the UI from that class. You may create more problems than solving.
You can either use a Broascast Receiver or, a much simplier solution, use [EventBus framework](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) that easily allows you to notify and send data from one thread to another.

Using EventBus takes four simple steps:

Implement any number of event handling methods in the subscriber:

```
public void onEvent(AnyEventType event) {}
```

Register subscribers:

```
eventBus.register(this);
```

Post events to the bus:

```
eventBus.post(event);
```

Unregister subscriber:

```
eventBus.unregister(this);
```